# R Data.Table Split Numeric Column and Do Operation

Tags: r, data.table

```
data=data.frame("VAR1"= c(105,607,111),
"VAR2"=c(7,19,13))
```

I have `VAR1` and wish to create `VAR2` with a simple rule, I take the first digit from `VAR1` and multiply it by 2 and then add the last two numbers, so it looks like this for digit 111 in `VAR1`: 2*1 + 11 = 13.

Comment: Are all your VAR1 3-digit long?

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

data <- data.table("VAR1"= c(105,607,111))

data[, VAR2 := as.numeric(substr(VAR1, 1, 1)) * 2 + as.numeric(substr(VAR1, 2, 3))]

  VAR1 VAR2
1:  105    7
2:  607   19
3:  111   13
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are always dealing with 3-digit numbers:

```
with(data, 2 * (VAR1 %/% 100) + VAR1 %% 100)
```

or

```
with(data, 2 * floor(VAR1 / 100) + VAR1 %% 100)
```

Since the post is tagged with `data.table`:

```
setDT(data)
data[, VAR2 := 2 * floor(VAR1 / 100) + VAR1 %% 100]
data

   VAR1 VAR2
1:  105    7
2:  607   19
3:  111   13
```

Answer (score 0):

First split the vector into individual elements, making sure they're numeric:

```
Split <- lapply(strsplit(data$VAR1, split = ""), as.numeric)
```

Then use `sapply` in this way:

```
data$VAR2 <- sapply(Split, function(x){
  sum(x[1]*2 + as.numeric(paste0(x[2], x[3])))
})

data
  VAR1 VAR2
1  105    7
2  607   19
3  111   13
```